# my page loading is frozen with Chrome status "waiting for api.mixpanel.com" - what is this and how can I avoid it?

Tags: javascript, performance, mixpanel

I'm having some intermittent internet connectivity issues now,
and the result is my webpage loading (for my website) is stuck.

The Chrome status in the lower corner says: "waiting for api.mixpanel.com"

Chrome developer tools does not open.

What is happening and how can I code my mixpanel api call to avoid this?
ie: my website is still operational and reachable by me, but mixpanel is not -- I would like the webpage to still load in this situation.

*** EDIT: Feb 6, 2013 to add additional info ***

@raylu I got my mixpanel javascript within the last month so it's quite recent.
I'm not sure how to get the mixpanel version but here's some fragments:

I put this in the < head > of my html page:

```
<!-- start Mixpanel -->
...
src=("https:"===e.location.protocol?"https:":"http:")+'//cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2.2.min.js';
...
)};b.__SV=1.2}})
```

Then, I have my html body content.
Then, I close the body with:

```
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">mixpanel.track('some tag');</script>

<script type="text/javascript">mixpanel.name_tag('some id');</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Then open the devtools and inspect your network connections?

Comment: @Bergi: The OP wrote: "Chrome developer tools does not open."

Comment: Must've misread that as "devtools *are* not open". I can't think of a reason that would prevent them from opening.

Comment: Can you show us how you've integrated the Mixpanel library? In particular, which version of the lib are you using and where do you call `.track`?

Comment: @raylu I've updated my question to give more info.  An additional question: if I make changes now, how will I test it?  I'm not having internet problems currently.  I need a mock broken mixpanel api...

Answer (score 1):

When `mixpanel.track` is called, the Mixpanel JS library fires off an XHR (for most browsers). This makes it look like your page is loading (spinner on the tab) until the request completes. The XHR is completely asynchronous, however, and won't affect the performance of any other JS on the page because it doesn't block any of it from running.

The only time this could be bad is if you pass a callback to `track`:

```
mixpanel.track('some event', {'some prop': 'some value'}, function() {
    window.location = '/thanks';
});
```

If you have no connection, the callback will never fire. As long as you're not depending on this behavior and just tracking, though, the worst case is you lose some events.